# "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick_drivers" doesn't work

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. I have installing problems.

"sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-actionlib" works fine, but

"sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick_drivers" don't.

I just get:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-joystick_drivers

Any Idea why?
I am working with Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55615/%22sudo-apt-get-install-ros-groovy-joystick_drivers%22-doesn%27t-work/) by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Underscores are replaced by hyphens in the Ubuntu packages. That means you have to run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers
```

Hint: You can use tab-completion while typing: hit "tab" while completing the package name.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-02-19**:
Note you could also use `apt-cache` to search for packages e.g. `apt-cache search ros.*joystick` shows the name of the package you were trying to install.  As well as a small description of the package.